'value' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use component accessors like .r or .g
extension MaterialCode on Color {
  MaterialColor toMaterialColor() {
    final List<double> strengths = <double>[.05];
    final Map<int, Color> swatch = {};

    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      strengths.add(0.1 * i);
    }

    for (final strength in strengths) {
      final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
      swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
        (r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round()).toInt(),
        (g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round()).toInt(),
        (b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round()).toInt(),
        1,
      );
    }

    return MaterialColor(value, swatch);
  }
}

This is extension method of making any color to material color .
in latest version of flutter 3.27 red, green, blue is replaced by r,g,b so i made changes accordingly but
in return statement value is depreciated so what will be possible answer?

You could literally copy the source code from the API docs for the current Color.value method.  But how exactly are you going to use that in the long run?  Why do you need to see a "value"?  The legacy "value" is a 32-bit int.  The new r/g/b/a are all floating point with a lot more precision.

The point is that MaterialColor's sole constructor expects an ARGB value as 32-bit integer, and the deprecation of the integer-based properties in Color makes converting from one to the other unnecessarily non-straightforward.

Maybe MaterialColor will be getting a new interface soon?  Or just be deprecated entirely?
